Jhipster 8 after running mvnw, BUILD SUCCESS but no link to click to open the webpage

C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne>mvnw

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 3.3.3 :: Startup profile(s) dev ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2024-09-04T02:55:30.742+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2024-09-04T02:55:30.791+08:00  INFO 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.AppOneApp              : Starting AppOneApp using Java 17.0.12 with PID 34664 (C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne\target\classes started by User in C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne)
2024-09-04T02:55:30.791+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.AppOneApp              : Running with Spring Boot v3.3.3, Spring v6.1.12
2024-09-04T02:55:30.792+08:00  INFO 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.AppOneApp              : The following 2 profiles are active: "dev", "api-docs"
2024-09-04T02:55:33.201+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.config.WebConfigurer   : Registering CORS filter
2024-09-04T02:55:33.238+08:00  INFO 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2024-09-04T02:55:33.238+08:00  INFO 34664 --- [  restartedMain] com.github.appone.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application fully configured
2024-09-04T02:55:33.671+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.appone.config.AsyncConfiguration     : Creating Async Task Executor
2024-09-04T02:55:33.794+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.a.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
2024-09-04T02:55:33.984+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [ app-one-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2024-09-04T02:55:34.630+08:00 DEBUG 34664 --- [ app-one-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Liquibase has updated your database in 645 ms
2024-09-04T02:55:34.660+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.incubating             : HHH90006001: Encountered incubating setting [hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type].  See javadoc on corresponding `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` constant for details.
2024-09-04T02:55:34.852+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.incubating             : HHH90006001: Encountered incubating setting [hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type].  See javadoc on corresponding `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` constant for details.
2024-09-04T02:55:34.853+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.incubating             : HHH90006001: Encountered incubating setting [hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type].  See javadoc on corresponding `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` constant for details.
2024-09-04T02:55:34.855+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.incubating             : HHH90006001: Encountered incubating setting [hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type].  See javadoc on corresponding `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` constant for details.
2024-09-04T02:55:34.892+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.incubating             : HHH90006001: Encountered incubating setting [hibernate.type.preferred_instant_jdbc_type].  See javadoc on corresponding `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` constant for details.
2024-09-04T02:55:36.697+08:00  WARN 34664 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne\target\classes\com\github\appone\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository' defined in com.github.appone.repository.search.UserSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
2024-09-04T02:55:36.736+08:00  INFO 34664 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-09-04T02:55:36.753+08:00 ERROR 34664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne\target\classes\com\github\appone\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository' defined in com.github.appone.repository.search.UserSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
        at com.github.appone.AppOneApp.main(AppOneApp.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository' defined in com.github.appone.repository.search.UserSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on DatabaseConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:571)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:536)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:286)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused: getsockopt
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:111)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doExists(IndicesTemplate.java:177)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.exists(IndicesTemplate.java:169)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.createIndexAndMappingIfNeeded(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:93)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:87)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused: getsockopt
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:64)
        ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:934)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:304)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:292)
        at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientHttpClient.performRequest(RestClientHttpClient.java:91)
        at co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransportBase.performRequest(ElasticsearchTransportBase.java:144)
        at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.exists(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:666)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(IndicesTemplate.java:177)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.739 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-04T02:55:36+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


java, maven, nodejs version:
C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne>java --version
openjdk 17.0.12 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9
Java version: 17.0.12, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.12+7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\Users\User\Desktop\fyp\AppOne>node --version
v20.17.0

I see the tutotrial all will have link to click like the attechment, but why mine didnt have
I think is something wrong with database and then I go into
"AppOne\target\classes\config\application-dev.yml" and change the password to my mysql's password but still didnt work. And also look through Github and other tab still dont have any solutions.
hoping can get the result as the attachment, and also any missout information I can add on.

It looks like you forgot to start Elasticsearch. Running the following command before starting your app should fix this:
docker compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up -d

